# Merging 2 or more raster stacks in 1 in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I have 2 (or more) raster stacks. Each one went to diverse processing (any kind of stuff) and both stacks maintained theirs extents and resolutions (as initially, both have same extent and resolution). And now I want to make them one stack, instead of 2. So, I would have a 'merged_stack' that would contain all raster from both (or more) stacks.
For example:

```
#creating some data
m1 = matrix(1,30,30)
m2 = matrix(2,30,30)
ma = matrix(10,30,30)
mb = matrix(20,30,30)

#transforming in raster
r1 = raster(m1)
r2 = raster(m2)
ra = raster(ma)
rb = raster(mb)

#now 2 different stacks
stack1 = stack(r1,r2)
{...} some stuff (like raster name changing, sums, multiplications, etc)
goes with stack1 (this stuff does not change extent or resolution of the rasters)

stacka = stack(ra,rb)
{...} diferent stuff goes with stack2 (same here)

#using 'merge' does not work
merged_stack = merge(stack1,stacka)
```

Any idea in how this could be made? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `stack` on stacks: `merged_stack <- stack(stack1, stacka)`

Comment: Yep, just `stack` the stacks ... keep in mind they need to have the same extent, resolution, etc.

Comment: What!? It works, thank you very much. =D

Comment: @StatnMap, do you want to post that as an answer so the question can be closed?

Comment: Ok. I added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they have the same projection, extent and resolution, you can use stack on stacks:

```
merged_stack <- stack(stack1, stacka)
```